# How to stop the terminal from wrapping lines

Tags: 11.10, gnome-terminal

Is there a way to tell the terminal not to wrap long lines. I wish to see a line in the same space without wrapping to the next one. I do not care if I can not see the end of the line just as long as the line stays in one. A horizontal scroll would be good for this also but for the moment the removal of the wrapping is what I need.

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/how-to-disable-line-wrap-in-a-terminal

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It depends on what application you are using.

If you are viewing a file or command output using `less`, passing the `-S` option (a.k.a. `--chop-long-lines`) will cause output to be chopped off rather than wrapping to a new line.  You can use the horizontal arrow keys to view the rest of the line.

For generic non full screen applications, you can turn off line wrapping by sending an appropriate escape sequence to the terminal:

```
tput rmam
```

This mode can be cancelled with a similar escape:

```
tput smam
```

Details on adjusting the behaviour for a few other command line tools can be found here:

http://tomayko.com/writings/StupidShellTricks

Comment: Nice link although I did not expect something like that to change the behavior. +1.

Comment: Very interesting.  I tried this with gnome terminal, and it sorta-kinda works, but it is also causing output to be chopped off.  What I'd prefer is for the terminal to 'pretend' it had infinite line width, so it would just keep writing the line and then I could retrospectively go see the rest of the line by resizing or scrolling in the terminal window somehow.  Is this possible?

Comment: Does this automatically reset when a new bash/sh is made? Eg, is this, or is this not; persistent?

Comment: It is a runtime configuration of the terminal rather than a user configuration.  So it won't carry over to a new terminal instance, but should carry forward to new things running in the terminal provided the behaviour isn't reset.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge Is there any way to enable wrap? I don't like moving left and right to read the rest of the text on line.

Comment: In my case, I wanted no-wrap because It was annoying to view a csv with lots of horizontal data on multiple lines, so much so that I was willing to cut off data, just to see at least some of the data on single lines.

My 2 solution are:

1. Only view some of the columns 

`cat myfile.csv | awk '{ FS=","; print $1,$2,$3 }'`

2. Don't cut anything off, just use less and then you can scroll horizontally by using left and right arrows!

`cat myfile.csv | less`

Caveat "less acts weird when a single field is long"

Answer (score 16):

To disable line wrapping in terminal more generally, you can use:

`setterm -linewrap off`

Answer (score -1):

Leaving aside the wrapping thing, you can zoom out/ zoom in in terminal to see all the content you need in one line.

For me is :

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> - to zoom in
- `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> - to zoom out

Hope this helps